# How to send a message from a Telegram bot in case of python script exception?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm working on my wetherstation which collects temperature and humidity every minute. To this project I would like to add a Telegram bot which sends me a message if the data record gets stopped.
I downloaded the [Telegram bot library](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and made some tests with my Telegram bot.
For now, my bot is able to answer if I request, for example, the current humidity by sending `/humidity` to my bot.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Simple Bot to reply to Telegram messages
# This program is dedicated to the public domain under the CC0 license.

"""
This Bot uses the Updater class to handle the bot.

First, a few handler functions are defined. Then, those functions are passed to
the Dispatcher and registered at their respective places.
Then, the bot is started and runs until we press Ctrl-C on the command line.

Usage:
Basic Echobot example, repeats messages.
Press Ctrl-C on the command line or send a signal to the process to stop the
bot.
"""

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import logging
import read_from_database


# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments bot and
# update. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')

def status(bot, update):
    zeitstempel = read_from_database.get_timestamp()
    update.message.reply_text('letzter Eintrag: {:%d.%m.%Y %H:%M}'.format(zeitste$

def temperatur(bot, update):
    temperatur = read_from_database.get_temperature()
#    update.message.reply_text('letzter Temperatureintrag: %s ' % temperatur + u'$
    update.message.reply_text('letzter Temperatureintrag: %s C' % temperatur)

def feuchtigkeit(bot, update):
    feuchtigkeit = read_from_database.get_humidity()
    update.message.reply_text('letzter Feuchtigkeitseintrag: %s %%' % feuchtigkei$

def echo(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


def error(bot, update, error):
    logger.warn('Update "%s" caused error "%s"' % (update, error))

def main():
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("status", status))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("feuchtigkeit", feuchtigkeit))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("temperatur", temperatur))

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    #dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I have no idea how to send out an `alarm` when my python script runs into an exception during the record. Is there a possibility to send a message from my python script without sending a request to my Telegram bot?

Comment: Improved grammar, code formatting

Answer (score 4):

use updater.bot.send_message to send message